# libGDX - How do I add a (mouse)joint to an Actor in scene2d

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, scene2d

If I have a GameStage with the following:

```
...
public GameStage() {
    world = WorldUtils.createWorld();
    setUpWorld();
    setupCamera();
    debugRenderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();
}

private void setUpWorld() {
    world = WorldUtils.createWorld();
    world.setContactListener(this);
    setupGround();
    setupBall();
    setupJoint();
}

private void setupBall() {
    ball = new Ball(WorldUtils.createBall(world));
    addActor(ball);
}

private void setupGround() {
    ground = new Ground(WorldUtils.createGround(world));
    addActor(ground);
}

private void setupJoint() {
    jointDef = new MouseJointDef();
    jointDef.bodyA = ???
    jointDef.collideConnected = true;
    jointDef.maxForce = 50f;
}
...
```

How do I reference the bodies within each actor so that I can add a joint between two bodies. Specifically I am trying to add a mousejoint to the ball body so that I can add a directional impulse (mousejoint is destroyed in touchup or if max impulse is reached). I set the ground as bodyA during the setupJoint method. In the touchdown method I set the bodyB as the ball. I then find the x and y values (unprojecting them first to move from World to local coordinates) from the touch and set the position of the mouse using jointDef.target.set. My problem is I cannot figure out to get the body from the actor. Here is an example of my createBall method in the WorldUtils class.

```
...
public static Body createBall(World world) {
    // BALL
    // Body Definition
    BodyDef ballDef = new BodyDef();
    ballDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
    ballDef.position.set(0, 10); // 1 Meter up not 1 pixel

    // Ball shape
    CircleShape ballShape = new CircleShape();
    ballShape.setRadius(.5f);

    // Fixture Definition
    FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
    fixtureDef.shape = ballShape;
    fixtureDef.density = 2.0f;
    fixtureDef.friction = .5f; // 0 to 1
    fixtureDef.restitution = .5f; // 0 to 1

    Body body = world.createBody(ballDef);
    body.createFixture(fixtureDef);
    body.resetMassData();
    body.setUserData(new BallUserData());
    ballShape.dispose();
    return body;
}
...
```

My Ball and Ground are defined like this

```
...
public class Ground extends GameActor {
  public Ground(Body body) {
    super(body);
  }

  @Override
  public GroundUserData getUserData() {
    return (GroundUserData) userData;
  }
}
```

I am sure I am doing something stupid or I am misunstanding how the connection between scene2d and box2d works.

Thanks

Comment: Can't you just store the body as a class member variable of the actor class?

Comment: Yes I figured this out and that's exactly whay I did. In my case I put it in GameActor which extends Actor. Thanks